# Problem with matching a specific extension only using find command in shell script

Tags: shell, perl

I want to make some changes on a list of XML files in a directory using shell script and some perl commands.
Here it is an example of perl commands:

```
find "." -name "*.xml" | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\s+/ /g' *
```

All Perl commands work fine, but the problem is, the shell script executes the commands even on itself, in other words, when I run the shell script the perl commands changes the shell scripts with all other XML files!!! 
NOTE: XML files and Shell script are located on the same directory, and should not this part of the command:

```
 find "." -name "*.xml"
```

match only the files with XML extension !!!

any suggestions please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your have a wild card, *, and the end of your command!

Comment: Thank you, it works. But could you explain please, what the first part does? that match only .xml files!

Comment: First part is fine as you expect. The problem is bash expands `*` into a list of the all file names (well all files that do not start with '.') in the current working dir. and passes all the output from your `find` command to your `xargs` command. And this is what you did NOT expected.

Comment: Thank you again for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Red Cricket, you have a `*` at the end of your command, **get rid of that**.

Also, I recommend using `-exec` and `sed`:

```
find -name '*.xml' -exec sed 's/\s\+/ /g' {} \;
```